# getElementById not working when I try to pass a variable into the parameter

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

```js
let id = 0;
const listings = document.querySelector(".results").querySelectorAll(".item");

listings.forEach((listing) => {

        // create the button HTML
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.setAttribute('id',`button${id}`);
        button.setAttribute('type', 'button');

        // testing button selection
        const test = document.getElementById(`button${id}`);
        console.log(test);

        // add the button to the specified div
        const div = listing.querySelector(".specific-div");
        div.appendChild(button);

        // increment id value
        id++;
    });
```

I am trying to add an onClick to the buttons that I create and thus I need to select them by ID. If I go to the JS console and type something like `document.getElementById("button1")` the console will return the correct button element. If I go into my code and change the variable to just a specific value, i.e

```
const test = document.getElementById("1");
console.log(test);
```

I also get the correct value returned. So the issue only arises when I do `getElementById(some_variable)`. I tried using just the id without the template string and it does not work either. `querySelector` doesn't work too, so I assume its a problem with the way I am implementing it not the method.

Comment: remove that `.` before `\`button${id}\`` in `const test = document.getElementById(\`.button${id}\`);`

Comment: it should be `const test = document.getElementById(\`button${id}\`)`;

Comment: The . was a mistake but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I only added it by accident when testing code

Comment: You can not select an element before you ad it to the DOM!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById` searches the *document* for the element with that ID.

You've created an element and given it that id, but you haven't added it to the document (with `div.appendChild(button);`) yet, so when you search for it there, it isn't found.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even notice/think about the order that I put that in.